# What is this port called? I want to guess it is for video

Tags: usb, port

What is this port called?

If this is off topic, please direct me to the appropriate place for my question

Looks equal in thickness to micro, slightly more narrow resulting in a more squared shape.

[image: Plugs]

Comment: That's just a cable. The port is what it plugs into.

Comment: Looks like Mini USB to me. Can you please measure the length and height in mm?

Comment: Looks like what Joren says - an older style camera USB connector used prior to USB-micro existing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit like USB port on (older) Nikon cameras, which is a UC-E6 port, I believe.